# Learning Flask: jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'name', got '.'

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am learning Flask but my code won't run and it looks fine. I have Googled the error and found very varied results, and so specific one for `expected token 'name', got '.'` but other symbols. I was testing the 404 page and it derives from base.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template                                                                 
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

app = Flask(__name__)
bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404

@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_server_error(e):
    return render_template('500.html'), 500

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

app.add_url_rule('/', 'index', index)

@app.route('/user/<name>')
def user(name):
    return render_template('user.html', name=name)
```

`base.html`...

```
{% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Flasky{% endblock %}

{% block navbar %}
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"
                         data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Flasky</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
        {% block.page_content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

`404.html`...

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Flasky - Page Not Found{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">
        <h1>Not Found!</h1>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

When trying to request a bunch of random letters to produce 404, the following happens...

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Feb/2020 18:39:19] "GET /asdfsadf HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/devel/learn/flask/myflasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/john/devel/learn/flask/myflasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1925, in dispatch_request
    self.raise_routing_exception(req)
  File "/home/john/devel/learn/flask/myflasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1907, in raise_routing_exception
    raise request.routing_exception
  File "/home/john/devel/learn/flask/myflasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/ctx.py", line 350, in match_request
    result = self.url_adapter.match(return_rule=True)
  File "/home/john/devel/learn/flask/myflasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/routing.py", line 1945, in match
    raise NotFound()
werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/devel/learn/flask/myflasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/john/devel/learn/flask/myflasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/john/devel/learn/flask/myflasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/john/devel/learn/flask/myflasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/john/devel/learn/flask/myflasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/john/devel/learn/flask/myflasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/john/devel/learn/flask/myflasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in handle_user_exception
    return self.handle_http_exception(e)
  File "/home/john/devel/learn/flask/myflasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1743, in handle_http_exception
    return handler(e)
  File "/home/john/devel/learn/flask/myflasky/hello.py", line 9, in page_not_found
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
  File "/home/john/devel/learn/flask/myflasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 140, in render_template
    ctx.app,
  File "/home/john/devel/learn/flask/myflasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 120, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/home/john/devel/learn/flask/myflasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1090, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "/home/john/devel/learn/flask/myflasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "/home/john/devel/learn/flask/myflasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/john/devel/learn/flask/myflasky/templates/404.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends "base.html" %}
  File "/home/john/devel/learn/flask/myflasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "/home/john/devel/learn/flask/myflasky/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/john/devel/learn/flask/myflasky/templates/base.html", line 29, in template
    {% block.page_content %}{% endblock %}
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'name', got '.'
```

I don't understand how to find the bug being reported here, and basically don't understand the output. It would be good if someone could give me pointers to what this error means, for example where it expects 'name' to be because I have no idea.

Comment: You have a typo in your `base.html`: `{% block.page_content %}{% endblock %}`. Just replace the dot after the `block` with a space and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I looked through your code and the first thing I noticed was that the route you visited, "/asdfsadf" doesn't exist. And your main concern should be that in your "base.html", it should be {% block page_content %} instead of {% block.page_content %}. Feel free to ask anything!